# WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec is a raw type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I got this weird warning on `WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec` and wasn't sure what type I should be passing into the `WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?>` as part of the initialization of this `requestSpec`.

```java
    
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestSpec = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri(uri);
    
    try {
          return requestSpec
              .header("Content-Type", HEADER_VALUE_CONTENT_TYPE)
              .retrieve()
              .bodyToMono(String.class)
              .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(config.getTimeoutInMilliseconds()))
              .block();
    
    } catch (WebClientResponseException e) {   // do something }
```

> WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec is a raw type. References to generic type
> WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec should be parameterized Java(16777788)

However, this works fine with `post()`, so I am curious to know what's the main difference

```java
    WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec = webClientBuilder.build().post().uri(uri);
```

*note: the `block()` is needed, it is a sync call*

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it seems to be only for `post()` which I am looking for setting up a spec for `get()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `WebClient` interface you will see that `get()` has return type of `RequestHeadersUriSpec<?>`, while `post()` has `RequestBodyUriSpec` which extends `RequestHeadersUriSpec<RequestBodySpec>`. While the `post` method's return type is parameterized through inheritance, the `get` method's is not. Hence the warning.

To avoid the warning you can simply provide the generic type for type declaration:

```java
WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> requestSpec = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks. Any possible/potential bugs can happen using generic type `<?>` declaration here?

Comment: I doubt, no. You control the generic type by building up the request, I don't think you can make any errors here. Usually though you would want to chain the calls on a `WebClient`, reads a lot better that way. So assign a `WebClient` to a variable (or inject it) and don't assign partial values to variables unless you find it necessary.